# Change font of footnote (thanks) mark on titlepage

Tags: fonts, footnotes, titles, authblk

I want to change the font to sans-serif of the footnote mark (or the `\thanks` mark) after the author's name. How do I achieve that? I can change the author's name and the footnote text using `\textsf`.

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{newcomputermodern}

\usepackage{authblk}

\title{Title}

\author{\textsf{Name}\thanks{\textsf{Footnote}}}

\begin{document}
    \maketitle
\end{document}
```

Comment: I think `\makeatletter
\def\@makefnmark{\@textsuperscript{\textsf{\@thefnmark}}}
\makeatother` shoudl do it, but the difference is hard to notice?

Comment: @PeterGrill Thanks, that works! Can you please add it as an answer so that I can accept it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following should do what you desire.

```
\makeatletter 
    \def\@makefnmark{\@textsuperscript{\textsf{\@thefnmark}}} 
\makeatother
```

The difference is very subtle though.